# span display inline not displaying at all on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

So I'm having a strange issue where all my spans that are `display : inline` just don't appear on safari even when I use the browser's console and hover the element in the DOM to get the preview of its dimension nothing appears and the box Model shows this [image: Box model Safari]

Whereas firefox or chrome shows the correct dimensions [image: Box model Firefox]

If I change the span display to `inline-block` everything appears as it should but I canno't use such css rule in this specific case because the word break won't work anymore, I'm using a span for each letter of my banner title to animate it with js + css so I need it to be `display : inline`
Here's the result with `display : inline` on firefox/chrome [image: display inline result]

And here with `inline-block`on firefox/chrome/safari [image: display inline-block result]

So as you can see using `inline-block` is not an option.

Also I checked my entire website for spans and none of them appear on safari unless I add `display : inline-block` so it's not specific to my banner title. The only common css to all my spans is this one

```
    span {
font-weight : 500;
line-height : 3rem;
/* 1rem = 10px in this case */
}
```

Apart from these two css rules most of them are just plain spans with sometimes `font-size` or `color` changes.

Edit :

To better show what I mean this is what happens when I hover my h1 element using Safari's dev tools
[image: Safari dev tools h1]

And here when I hover any span inside that h1 while it's using `display : inline`
[image: Safari dev tools span inline]

And finally when I hover a span inside my h1 while using `display : inline-block`
[image: Safari dev tools span inline-block]

Edit 2 : After hours of search it seems like the problem comes from the font itself, when I use another one Safari shows my spans elements, still no idea on how to fix that but in case it might point someone in the right direction in the future I'm leaving this note

Comment: What do you mean don't appear, when you inspect the place where it should be the bounds appear or the element goes out of the screen?

Comment: Remove the font-weight property and see if the text appear again, it could be that the font don't have a 500 weight and no fallback

Comment: Updated my question @teefars I tried to remove the font-weight rule, nothing changed

Comment: It seems the element is off screen, It looks like a positioning issue, try setting `position:relative` to them and/or to the parent. Do you have any links to the website I can try to check?

Comment: They all have position relative set, aswell as a top position from 1em to 0 set in their animation, here's the link https://domaine-marguerite-carillon.catapulpe.fr/ as you will see if you're on safari a lot of content is missing (navigation links for instance) these missing elements are spans with display : inline too

Comment: I see, the thing is, inline elements don't respect all the rules of related positioning, they are weird. I believe the solution is even simpler. Instead of moving with weird positioning, just transform them. Add a `transform:translateY(-20px); opacity:0;` and when animating just `transform:translateY(0);` to each letter.

Comment: Changed it on my local version still nothing, also my other spans are not using animations and they don't show up aswell, if you can compare chrome vs safari versions of the site you will see what I mean

Comment: I'm on windows and safari isn't supported on windows. If you're using windows don't expect to test things in safari. Sorry, but again, if they are properly positioned just translateY and they'll remain in place.

Comment: I'm using Browserstack and my boss has a Mac and we have the issue on both. Yeah I got the translateY() thing but only my banner spans use positionning like this, for my naviation bar or any other spans on the site I have the issue where it just doens't appear

Comment: Sorry can't debug, hope someone helps. I tried checking but there are a lot of properties that could mess with inline elements. Try removing padding, positioning, margins, rem measurements, inherit atributes. IDK seems like something trivial. inline elements are meant to be paragraph text with maybe images. They don't accept many other block properties and when that happens it's up to the browser to manage it. Welcome to crossbrowser hell.

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help someone facing the same problem, I finally found the problem, it came directly from the font files, I uploaded them again to my server and it worked